# WCF Sessions Issue

Tags: wcf

I read some articles about Sessions in WCF and its difference between Asp.Net sessions.
Can you please tell me

a)  The example scenarios in which we can make use of WCF Sessions.

b)  The benefits of using WCF Sessions in such scenarios.

c)  Code implementation of such scenarios

Comment: This does not answer to the question but you can read about WCF lifecycle concepts and sessions management here : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff183865.aspx. It is a great article.

Comment: [Session in WCF is very different from ASP.NET session.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8321269/how-to-use-session-in-wcf/8321339#comment10257643_8321269)

Comment: Also, from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752234.aspx): "ASP.NET session state and WCF sessions are very different things. See the [Session](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms751429.aspx) for details on WCF sessions."