# Using the Session in WCF

Tags: c#, wcf, session

Here's what I'm trying to do to use the `Session` in my WCF application:

```
 System.Guid guid = System.Guid.NewGuid();
 string id = guid.ToString();
 HttpContext.Current.Session[id] = "AnyThing";
```

But I'm receiving this error message:

> Object Reference not set to instance of Object.

Is this the right approach for using the `Session` in a WCF application? Or is there another way to store data within WCF?

Comment: Session in WCF is **very different** from ASP.NET session. The WCF session is **NOT** designed to store data or somthing like that - it's only purpose is to keep a service class "alive" on the server for a particular client, so that a series of calls (part of that session) are always sent to and handled by the same service class instance on the server

Comment: From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752234.aspx): "ASP.NET session state and WCF sessions are very different things. See the [Session](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms751429.aspx) for details on WCF sessions."

Answer (score 5):

You will need to enable [ASP.NET Compatibility Mode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa702682.aspx)

web.config

```
<system.serviceModel>
  <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" />
</system.serviceModel>
```

Your WCF services need to have the [AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.activation.aspnetcompatibilityrequirementsattribute.aspx) set to Required or Allowed.

```
[AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Required)]
public class CalculatorService : ICalculatorSession
```

Comment: When i am using Above Code the client side through the Error is :protocol exception was unhandled by user code.Please give me the solution of this Error

Comment: Error Message : The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error.

Comment: Take a look at this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2449158/session-variable-in-wcf-application)