# Error using session in WCF Service

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, wcf, c#-4.0

I am using the below sample function in wcf project. It's working fine internally. When i am calling this function from outside of the hosted service. It returns the error.

```
Object reference not set to be an instance of an object.
```

I find that line HttpContext.Current.Session["UserSession"] // Error Code

```
try
{
    if (HttpContext.Current.Session["UserSession"] != null)
    {

    }
    else
    {

    }
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    return ex.Message;
}
```

But i want to user the session variable. Please help me to solve this.

Comment: `eles`? Wouldn't be `else`? And please read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8321269/how-to-use-session-in-wcf
let us see your's service and web.config

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
if (HttpContext.Current.Session.Contains("UserSession"))
{
  if (HttpContext.Current.Session["UserSession"] != null)
  {

  } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It means your session variable is empty.
Try using cache instead of session as session value is different for all pc's